# Automatic generation of migration SQL for Flyway

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, flyway

Is it possible for new Flyway migrations to be generated by JPA/Hibernate's automatic schema generation when a new model / field etc. are added via Java code.

It would be useful to capture the auto-generated SQL and save it directly to a new Flyway migration, for review / editing / committing to a project repository.

Thank you in advance for any assistance or enlightenment you can offer.

Comment: Some relevant discussions here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536256/combine-hibernates-automatic-schema-creation-and-database-versioning

Comment: Thank you @JamieB, we ended up just dealing with it as a chore.  Crafting the SQL for each migration by hand.  Still evaluation between flyway and maybe Liquibase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flyway doesn't have built-in support for diff, I use liquidbase within a maven spring boot project and changelogs can be created from JPA/hibernate changes by using:

```
mvn liquibase:diff
```

All of the options for liquibase diff are located here: 
http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/maven_diff.html

Comment: Thanks this is a what I ended up doing.  Honestly I'd forgotten about this question.

Answer (score 18):

If your IDE of choice is IntelliJ IDEA, I'd recommend using the [JPA Buddy](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15075-jpa-buddy) plugin to do this. It can generate Flyway migrations by comparing your Java model to the target DB.

You can use it to keep your evolving model and your SQL scripts in sync.
Also, it can create the init script if your DB is empty.

Once you have it installed and have Flyway as your Maven/Gradle dependency, you can generate a migration like this:
[image: Generating Flyway migration with JPA Buddy]

Comment: plus one! which tool do you use for GIF screen recording?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to generate the update SQL automatically, you can ask Hibernate to do so; just add the lines below to your Spring Boot configuration:

```ini
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source=metadata
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=update
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=update.sql
```

When you execute the application, this will generate a file named `update.sql` on the root of your project. Now, you can just copy and paste them into your Flyway migration.

This was adapted from this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36966419/679240 ; it is basically the same logic, except that one wants to generate a database creation script, while I needed an update script, instead.

BTW, if you want to replace the names of the foreign keys on the script with more readable ones, you could use this regex: `^(alter table .*?)(\w+)(\s+add constraint )\w+( foreign key \()(.*?)(\).*)` with this replacement: `$1$2$3fk_$2__$5$4$5$6`; this will change the names of the FKs in the script to `fk_name_of_the_table__name_of_the_field`.