# How do I perform database diff generation with Quarkus and Hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, quarkus, liquibase-hibernate

Currently, I'm using PostgreSQL for my database and Quarkus with Hibernate ORM. For a while, I just used Hibernate's default HBM2DDL. Eventually, I discovered that it couldn't update every change I was making to my entities. Now I'd like to use a proper database migration tool and run something that will generate diff SQL files that I can edit before putting into production.

My question is: how do I set up Quarkus and Hibernate ORM entities so that I can generate SQL diff files for database migrations?

Here's what I've tried so far:

When using Quarkus, the main two supported database migration tools appear to be [Flyway](https://quarkus.io/guides/flyway) and [Liquibase](https://quarkus.io/guides/liquibase). I tried integrating each of these separately and ran into a number of issues:

- Integrating Flyway worked nicely, but trying to hand write SQL migration files by studying my PanacheEntities and copying out Hibernate-generated changes became super tedious.
- As a temporary workaround, I used Quarkus's Dev UI to [generate "initial migration" SQL files](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#flyway) for several different versions of my application, and then I went through and edited each file so that it would migrate correctly. This worked, but still required a lot of time and trial and error.
- I discovered that [using JPA Buddy is a common answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67935661). Sadly, generating diff migrations with JPA Buddy has since become a paid feature, so I would like to look elsewhere.
- I restarted to a point before Flyway and integrated Liquibase, which was even faster to set up by reusing the SQL files I made for Flyway. I got the migration working, but still needed a solution to generate SQL diffs. Despite [Liquibase having support for generating a diff with Maven](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/commands/maven-diff.html), Quarkus's Liquibase page does not seem to have any support for it, or make any mention of how to improve writing migrations for future versions.
- I tried adding [liquibase-hibernate](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate) as a dependency to the project, which also involved adding several other things to my `pom.xml` file, making a `liquibase.properties` file (even though I already have an `application.properties` file), and attempting to write an implementation of the `CustomMetadataFactory` class. It seems promising, but Quarkus changes things about Hibernate which prevents me from being able to exactly follow a tutorial for using Liquibase and Hibernate together.

I find myself pretty stuck at this point. Generating a diff between a local development database and my current JPA entity changes seems to be possible with simpler Hibernate projects and with Spring Boot. What can I do?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I also can't find a possibility for diff generation with quarkus liquibase plugin.